# What to look for in a Large Touchscreen

Tags: display, touchscreen

I am making a kiosk application and need a large touchscreen monitor for the same.

I am looking for large touch screen display(24inch-27inch) which can work with raspberry pi 3 B+ and RPi zero with raspbian OS. I have seen various Dell, hanspree, viewsonic and planar displays but I am not sure if they work well with above raspberry pi. I want to use just plug n play method to use the touch and display.

What do I need to know in order to insure this will work with a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Welcome -- but as per the help center, shopping recommendations are explicitly [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), meaning you can't ask someone to recommend a specific product for you.  However, you can ask what you need to look for when shopping, and I have edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks for your kind support and clarifications over my question. I'll take care of it in near future.

Comment: This is the question I search answer for! Could it be reformulated to ask about various solutions order in ease of implementation? And names of the tech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I would watch out for:

You want something that uses HDMI for video and USB for touch data. This will ensure that you can plug the display directly into the Pi without needing any sort of adapters.

The harder part is making sure that the software is compatible with the Pi. See if the spec sheet or manufacturer's website says anything about Linux drivers, or try searching online for a couple different models. Raspbian has come a long way in terms of hardware support, but there are still many devices that don't work with it. Chances are nowadays, if there's a Linux driver for a device, it's probably either preinstalled on the Pi or easy to install otherwise.

Comment: Pretty sure the USB protocol for a touchscreen is more or less the same as the one for mice: Universal and open, i.e., these devices don't normally use proprietary or custom drivers at all, and the packaging will say they are okay for Windows/Mac/Linux.  This being the case it is probably fine to get anything normal seeming, although it does not hurt to search around with the model number and "linux" to see if there are any problems reported online.

Comment: I've had the unfortunate experience of buying a touchscreen that didn't work with the Pi, so I'd still caution against buying something that isn't confirmed to work on Linux.

Comment: I had contacted some manufacturers. Some of them are saying that any OS can be installed on monitor. It doesn't come with any software dependency. What does it mean?

Comment: @WesleyChalmers This was a USB + HDMI based touchscreen, or something that used the TFT and/or GPIOs?

Comment: @goldilocks It was a USB/HDMI one, yeah; I got it from a friend. There was some proprietary shenanigans with the USB connection and vendor drivers (which weren't available for Linux) were required.

Comment: @PriyaGarg That's a great sign - if any OS can be used with the touchscreen, it's almost certainly supported by Raspbian. "No software dependency" probably means that no vendor drivers are required and it should be plug-and-play